# multiple single line equations with part of text

Tags: equations, subequations

I am not able to align them properly.

How can I have multiple line equation, with each equation is labeled properly.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation} \label{eq:sr}
\mbox{Inductive reactance as:} X_L = 2 \pi f L = \omega L \\
\mbox{Capacitive reactance as:} X_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi f C} = \frac{1}{\omega C} \\
\mbox{Total circuit reactance:} X_T = X_L - X_C or X_C - X_L \\
\mbox{Total circuit impedance:} Z = \sqrt{R^2 + X_T^2} = R + jX \\
\mbox{When} X_L = X_C \rightarrow 2 \pi f L  = \frac{1}{2 \pi f C} \\
f_r = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L C}} (Hz) or \omega_r = \frac{1}{L C} (rads) \\
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of `equation` you should use `gather` or `align` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple alignments with enumeration is best achieved with something like `alignat` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \text{Inductive reactance as:}  & \quad & X_L &= 2 \pi f L = \omega L \\
  \text{Capacitive reactance as:} &       & X_c &= \frac{1}{2 \pi f C} = \frac{1}{\omega C} \\
  \text{Total circuit reactance:} &       & X_T &= X_L - X_C or X_C - X_L \\
  \text{Total circuit impedance:} &       &   Z &= \sqrt{R^2 + X_T^2} = R + jX \\
                      \text{When} &       & X_L &= X_C \rightarrow 2 \pi f L = \frac{1}{2 \pi f C} \\
                                  &       & f_r &= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L C}} \text{ (Hz) or }
                                                   \omega_r = \frac{1}{L C} \text{ (rads)}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Everything is ok, but may I know why you used \quad there ?

Comment: May I know how can I disable the label for certain line in the above equation alignment ?

Comment: @statisticalbeginner: Insert `\nonumber` before ``\\`` on the same line.